# Django automatically fill user detail

Tags: django

I am using the Django generic CreateView to add an entry. Here is my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And my View:

```
class MyModelAdd(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'mymodeladd.html'
    fields = ('id', 'purpose', 'is_visible')

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/myapp/success'
```

How do i fill the created_by field with the logged in user(request.user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `form_valid` function.

```
class MyModelAdd(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'mymodeladd.html'
    fields = ('id', 'purpose', 'is_visible')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(MyModelAdd, self).form_valid(form)
```